# Why are threejs apps not running in mozilla firefox

Tags: firefox, three.js, webgl

I have recently done a fresh install of Linux SUSE and now Firefox is not displaying threejs.

I have updated the

```
about:config webgl.force-enabled to true
```

The browser console gives the following error message.

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 73 three.min.js:578:133
THREE.WebGLRenderer: Error creating WebGL context. three.min.js:581:370

Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init. three.min.js:581:104
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed. three.min.js:581:104
Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init. three.min.js:581:129
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed. three.min.js:581:129
Error: WebGL: Error during native OpenGL init. three.min.js:581:189
Error: WebGL: WebGL creation failed. three.min.js:581:189
TypeError: a is null
```

I would like to know what I need to do to get my page to display the three.js scene appropriately without hacking my system as obviously I require the page to display on all browsers.

Comment: The scene displays perfectly well in the chromium browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of firefox ?  Assure its 43 or above ... have you been mucking about with settings ? to reset firefox settings to default go to URL

```
about:support
```

to factory reset all your settings including WebGL hit

```
Give Firefox a tune up  --> refresh firefox
```

... below is a screenshot of what this gives you if you want to manually change WebGL pertinent settings  ... in URL enter :

```
about:config
```

then search on `webgl` to give you this listing of default settings :

[image]

WebGL does provide for bleeding edge settings which can/do cause browsers/graphicsCards to barf ... so try to run a simple WebGL site ...  let us know how you get on

Comment: aren't both of those windows only flags?

Comment: Works for me on my mac. Thanks.

Comment: Yes That worked.  It informed me that opengl had been disabled due to  a crash.  So I used  Give Firefox a tune up  --> refresh firefox   As you suggested   And it now works..   with firefox On openSUSE.   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found a forum post on line that clued me into the existence of `gfx.crash-guard.status.glcontext` which is what turns off WebGL after a crash. Resetting it as shown below got me running again without touching any other settings.[image]

**Edit:** I just noticed that on my macbook pro, this value becomes "user set" to "2" (not 3 as shown above) the moment I reload the about:support or the page containing WebGL code (but the web page renders ok and web GL stuff still seems to work).
[image]